# create VirtualService for kiali, tracing, grafana

Tags: istio

I am trying to expose kiali on my default gateway. I have other services working for apps in the default namespace but have not been able to route traffic to anything in the istio namespace

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - '*'
      tls:
        httpsRedirect: true
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: https
        protocol: HTTPS
      hosts:
        - '*'
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
        privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
        serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
    - kiali.dev.example.com
  gateways:
    - gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 20001
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was I had mTLS enabled and kiali does not have a sidecar thus can not be validated by mTLS. the solution was to add a destination rule disabling mTLS  for it.

```
apiVersion: 'networking.istio.io/v1alpha3'
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  host: kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define an ingress gateway and make sure that the hosts in the gateway match the hosts in the virtual service. Also specify the port of the destination. See the [Control Ingress Traffic](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/) task.

Comment: I have my gateway defined, I will add it. Also the docs say that  if you only have 1 port on the service you don't have to define it. with that said I have manually set it and still no worky.

Comment: I have updated my answer: and make sure that the hosts in the gateway match the hosts in the virtual service.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked!

I ran

```sh
istioctl proxy-config routes istio-ingressgateway-866d7949c6-68tt4 -n istio-system -o json > ./routes.json
```

to get the dump of all the routes. The kiali route got corrupted for some reason. I deleted the virtual service and created it again, that fixed it.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  gateways: 
    - istio-system/my-gateway
  hosts: 
    - 'mydomain.com'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /kiali/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 20001
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: 'networking.istio.io/v1alpha3'
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  host: kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
---
```

Note: hosts needed to be set, `'*'` didnt work for some reason.